# How do i use cocos2d with Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I downloaded the lastest version of cocos2d but I am confused as to how to use it with my current project. Can anyone show me how to use it with xcode. I'm looking to design a 2D maze. Do i have to import something ? Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two years later and you can just download and install Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com) which includes cocos2d and many example projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to drag the cocos2d files into your project, then they will be available.

This is a very helpful step-by-step resource on how to do that.

http://monoclestudios.com/cocos2d_whitepaper.html

As far as designing your game, get started, play around, and look at the sample code. There are also very helpful folks on the message board.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of Cocos2D-iPhone (0.8.1) I've put together a tutorial at:
http://www.antonmills.com/?p=233

It includes everything you need for setting up the Xcode template, adding sprites and a small animation loop in a Hello World type of application, might be helpful :)

also deffinitely check the forum John posted, very helpful lot :)

Cheers,
anton.