# Can't install cocos2d templates on XCODE 4.2

Tags: xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I can't successfully install the Cocos2D templates for XCODE 4.2 in Mac Leopard 10.6.8.

When I call the ./install-templates.sh -f -u command line I get a lot of "command not found" errors (for rsync, mkdir etc). I also tried to type "sudo" on the terminal and I get the same error... it seems like a path problem right?

The most curious is that if I login using the root account the installation works, but when I come back to my development user, I open XCode and still can't see the templates :-(

Any idea?

Comment: Check this link out as i had the same problem

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16276532/2088030

Answer (score 0):

run the Repair Permissions utility in the Disk Utility program for your partition. it's harmless, good maintenance practice, and might solve your issues.

Comment: it didn't work sorry :_(

Comment: How to install Cocos 2D , I using IOS 5, Xcode 4.2.1